# pacemaker corosync service ignored

Tags: cluster-computing, pacemaker

Two Node cluster Node A , Node B .

Service X running on Node A, Node B is DC.

We are using stack corosync with Pacemaker.
Failure Timeout is 10 sec . 
Target-Role is started .

Events happens like this
Node A sends event to Node B Service X is down
Node B prints Ignoring expired failure for Service X
After this Service X is never restarted by the Cluster.

Now questions are:

1. Why is Node B (DC) ignoring the expired failure?
2. Even for this time DC ignored but as the Service X is down, Node A should monitor the service and again send failure status to Node B and at that time Node B should restart the service. Why this no hapenning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Reason for this may be time difference between two servers (DC and Other Machine) .

So , DC thinks that this event is old and ignore it . Please sync time and then try to re-create the issue .

Answer (score 1):

U can  add the following property to your crm configuration which will try to start failed, expired resources.

```
 start-failure-is-fatal="false"
```